# Create new rows using exist row in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to create new rows from existing row in SQL server view

### Original view is like below

```
              salecount   

  HP           56
  Dell         32
  Acer         21
  Asus         55
 ..........many rows
```

### Output view is like below

```
                    salecount
HP Laptop           44.8 (56*0.8)

HP Desktop          11.2 (56*0.2)
  Dell              32
  Acer              21
  Asus              55

 ..........many rows
```

I don't know how to use insert into inside CTE

```
,CTE_SalesSeparated
AS(
SELECT [Date]
      ,[Country]
      ,[Year]
      ,[Brand]
     -- ,Insert into 'HP Laptop'  = [SaleCount]*0.8
     --              'HP Desktop' = [SaleCount]*0.2
FROM CTE_Sales
)
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
WITH CTE_SalesSeparated AS (
      SELECT s.[Date], s.[Country], s.[Year],
             coalesce(ld.[Brand] + ' ' + which, s.Brand) as Brand,
             s.SalesCount * coalesce(ld.factor, 1) as SalesCOunt
      FROM CTE_Sales s LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT 'HP' as Brand, 'LapTop' as which, 0.8 as factor UNION ALL
            SELECT 'HP' as Brand, 'DeskTop' as which, 0.2 as factor
           ) ld
           ON s.Brand = ld.Brand
     )
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, This looks like what I want to do, I will try run this now and see if I can get through this. Thanks!